# Is it possible to use Umbraco's admin login to secure an external MVC application

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-membership, umbraco

I have a Umbraco website and an MVC application and I would like to use Umbraco login/administration to secure my MVC application. Does anyone know how I can do this?

Thanks

Comment: Please elaborate a bit more as this question doesn't clarify what the desired result is? Do you want the entire MVC application behind Umbraco's login (e.g. inaccessible unless logged in as an Umbraco User) or do you want to authenticate with Umbraco and use the profile on your MVC app? What version Umbraco are you using? Thanks

Comment: What I would like is to be able to add the Authorize attribute on controller of my MVC app, then when I'm logged in Umbraco, I'm allowed to view those pages, when I'm not I get redirected to Umbraco loggin. I'm using 6.1.1

Answer (score 1):

The latest versions of Umbraco works right along side managing members with membership, with the standard System.Web.Security. I use Umbraco 6 but it was added after 4.1 I think. A brief summary of setting it up.

1. Create some login forms in Umbraco using the Windows membership code in your controller, (there are many tutorials on the internet).
2. Add a member type in the Umbraco admin members section.
3. Set the defaultMemberTypeAlias to your member type in your web.config.
4. Set up public access by clicking right on your pages in the Umbraco admin content panel.
5. Login and you should see your member in the members section.
6. Add some code to your menu to show and hide member pages.

There is a very nice NuGet package with the code to get you started:

> PM> Install-Package CWS.Umbraco.Standard.Membership

Comment: Members (public) and Users (admin/editors) use different authentication mechanisms, it sounds like you're describing Members, and the question seems to be about Users. (Member authentication uses the standard provider model User authentication does not)